# How to determine function parameter type in python?

Tags: python, types

For example I have a poorly documented library. I have an object from it and I want to know what are the types of the arguments certain method accepts.

In IPython I can run

```
In [28]: tdb.getData?
Signature: tdb.getData(time, point_coords, sinterp=0, tinterp=0, data_set='isotropic1024coarse', getFunction='getVelocity', make_modulo=False)
Docstring: <no docstring>
File:      ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyJHTDB/libJHTDB.py
Type:      method
```

but it does not give me the types of the arguments. I don't know exactly what is the type of `point_coords`.

Comment: If it's a native python function, there are no strict types of names in the C sense. You could even pass a ham sandwich as `point_coords`.

Comment: Unless it uses the new type annotations feature, that is.

Comment: Read the source and look for relevant comments and what operations they try to perform on the argument, or look for usage examples. The Github page says to look at the [`test_plain`](https://github.com/idies/pyJHTDB/blob/master/pyJHTDB/test.py#L45) function, which seems to indicate `point_coords` should be an Nx3 NumPy array of float32 dtype.

Comment: you can try to use two question marks instead of one in interactive (`??`) to see the function definition. It might help to understand what is expected.

Comment: Python is dynamically typed ([if it quacks like a duck...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing)) so any object that "looks" like the expected type works for a calculation but that makes your task difficult. You need to poke around the code (perhaps find other consumers) to see what the requirements are.

Comment: use smarts ... what do you think point_coords looks like? based on its name I woudl assume its a list of [(x,y),...] or [(x,y,z),..] ... I would try both ...I would also look at the code in the file mentioned ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, functions in Python accept arguments of any type, so you cannot define what type it expects.

Still, the function probably does make some implicit assumptions about the received object.

Take this function for example:

```
def is_long(x):
    return len(x) > 1000
```

What type of argument `x` does this function accept? Any type, as long as it has length defined.

So, it can take a string, or a list, or a dict, or any custom object you create, as long as it implements `__len__`. But it won't take an integer.

```
is_long('abcd')  # ok
is_long([1, 2, 3, 4])  # ok
is_long(11)  # not ok
```

**To answer the question:** How can you tell what assumtions the function makes?

- read the documentation
- read the doc string (try `help(funcname)`)
- guess: Pass any argument to it and see how it fails. If it fails with *AttributeError: X instance has no attribute 'get_value'*, it expects something with `get_value`.